# SQL Server Incorrect syntax near '`'

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below SQL which I am trying to execute against a Microsoft SQL Server.

```
$rs = odbc_exec($conn, "INSERT INTO tGuest (`GuestName`, `GuestEmailAddress`, `GuestPassword`, `GuestCity`, `GuestCountry`) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test');");
```

However I ened up with the below error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '`'.
```

I can not see anything wrong with the SQL code so am not sure if I am missing something or there is something else wrong.

Comment: Just remove '`' ;)

Comment: remove this ; and you are done

Comment: Even if you use ODBC, you still have to use the native SQL code supported by each target DBMS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SQL Server` uses `[]`/`"` to quote [identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx):

> **Delimited identifiers**
>
> Are enclosed in **double quotation marks (") or brackets ([ ])**. Identifiers that comply with the rules for the format of identifiers
>   might not be delimited.

```
$rs = odbc_exec($conn, "INSERT INTO tGuest ([GuestName], [GuestEmailAddress], [GuestPassword], [GuestCity], [GuestCountry]) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test');");
```

In your case you could also skip it at all, because your identifiers are valid:

```
INSERT INTO tGuest(GuestName,GuestEmailAddress,GuestPassword,GuestCity,GuestCountry) 
VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test');
```

---

Your naming convention seems to be redundant. If table is named `tGuest` then there is no need to prefix columns with `Guest`.

Comment: I actually like this naming conversion and use it myself. It's very useful when writing multiple joins queries since you don't need to use the table name or alias as a part of the column identifier. Also, it prevents almost completely the use of reserved words as column names.